# Did British Airways or Air France use Professional Flight Engineers on Concorde?

Tags: commercial-aviation, crew, concorde, flight-engineer

Did British Airways or Air France use Professional Flight Engineers (non-pilot PFEs) on  Concorde or were the flight engineers required to be pilots (*not necessarily qualified to fly Concorde*) who were trained and qualified/certificated as flight engineers?

Answer (score 5):

**Air France**

Flight engineers were called "OMN" (officiers  mécaniciens navigants) and had no pilot rating for Concorde. They were not required to be pilots at all.

- PIC and copilot had to obtain the ATP licence and a "Qualification Concorde" (Concorde rating).
- OMN had to obtain a "Brevet de Mécanicien Navigant" (Flight Engineer’s Licence) and a "Qualification Concorde" (Concorde rating).

You may confirm this by looking at [BEA report for F-BTSC accident](https://www.bea.aero/docspa/2000/f-sc000725a/pdf/f-sc000725a.pdf).

**British Airways**

Licenses are similar:

- For pilots: ATP license and Concorde rating.
- For flight engineers: Flight Engineer license and Concorde rating.

This is confirmed in [AAIB report for G-BOAF accident](https://assets.publishing.service.gov.uk/media/5423017ded915d1371000b3d/6-1989_G-BOAF.pdf).

---

None of the civil aviation flight engineers I can think of from [Latécoère](https://buffaloairpark.com/tag/latecoere-28-3/) to the FADEC introduction were ever required to be pilots.

See also: [Did Flight Engineers progress to be pilots?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/14535/3201) a question from the early days of this stack.